# Spring Boot: Setting Hibernate naming strategy with @DataJpaTest and Flyway

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, junit, h2, flyway

I have noticed an odd behavior when trying to use the @DataJpaTest annotation in a Spring Boot test that also uses Flyway.

Given the following entity class:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  private String columnA;
  private String columnB;

  public String getColumnA() {
      return columnA;
  }

  public void setColumnA(String columnA) {
      this.columnA = columnA;
  }

  public String getColumnB() {
      return columnB;
  }

  public void setColumnB(String columnB) {
      this.columnB = columnB;
  }
}
```

The following Spring repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String> {
}
```

The following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class JpaTestApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

  @Test
  public void canSaveAndFetch() {
      MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
      myEntity.setColumnA("a");
      myEntity.setColumnB("b");

      myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
      Optional<MyEntity> myEntityOptional = myEntityRepository.findById("a");
      Assert.assertTrue(myEntityOptional.isPresent());
  }
}
```

The test works fine by itself because auto-ddl is on and H2 is creating the tables.

However, if I wish to define my own schema then I add Flyway to the POM and create a migration, e.g. in resources/db/migration/V1__Schema.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE my_entity (
  column_a VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  column_b VARCHAR
);
```

Now the same test will fail because JPA is not using the default SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy anymore.

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "MYENTITY0_.COLUMNA" not found

This would seem to be a simple fix by setting

> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy

However, whether I put it in application.properties, or in a @TestPropertySource, or create a PhysicalNamingStrategy bean... nothing affects the behavior. How can I tell JPA in this test context that I want to use the SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy which maps "columnA" to "column_a"?

Comment: did you ever sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue - this property (`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy`) was ignored (alongside other `spring.jpa.hibernate` properties). It was caused by the class that extended `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration` and overwrote the method `protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties()` from class `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration`. Removing that class (which wasn't necessary after all) solved the problem and allow the `HibernateJpaConfiguration` class to apply all properties from the configuration file.